# Dataflow API retries several times after data format exception

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I found this as a required improvement for dataflow API or I may be wrong.

I created a batch dataflow and by mistake one of the lines in my input file had invalid data format.

So the pipeline job gave DataFormatException. But instead of stopping the job then itself it retried several times ~4 times before stopping the job.

I see this as a wrong behavior. When a batch dataflow receives an invalid data format, it should stop the job then itself instead of retrying several times and then stopping the job.
Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Dataflow is trying to build in some fault tolerance. That's a good thing. And this behaviour is clearly documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/faq) ("How are Java exceptions handled in Dataflow?")

If you don't want this behaviour, just write your own exception handling code, and bail out if you don't want it to be retried.

Comment: This is correct - Dataflow retries failing data processing tasks on failure. This is done to mask transient failures, such as network connectivity errors or transient bugs in framework or user code. It is not possible to automatically classify errors into transient/permanent, so we retry all failures.